# use socket.io in chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Actually i want use socket on chrome extension.Connection should start when i open tab and it will get disconnect until chrome will get close now if i will create socket connection on content script then every time socket will get disconnect and connect again when page will get refresh so that
I have created connection on  background script.
background script code:

```
chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(function callback(tabId, info){
socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');       
});
```

Now i want to use same socket on content script..
for this i have made a callback on chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener.
Callback request has came at content script but `emit` and `on` doesn't work

background script code:

```
  chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener( (request, sender,  sendResponse)=> {
sendResponse(JSON.stringify(socket))
})
```

Comment: "It does not work" is not a proper problem description.

Comment: Edit your post to add clarifications. Comments may be deleted at any time. You should never need to read comments to understand the question.

Comment: `JSON.stringify(socket)` produces a plain string which doesn't have any socket methods. Messaging won't work anyway because messaging uses JSON.stringify internally. You can't send complex objects via messaging. To reuse the socket you'll have to make your content script send requests to the background script which will perform the actual socket communication accordingly. Also, you really can benefit from using one of the primary programming tools: debugger. It's buit-in in Chrome as *devtools*. It allows you to inspect the variables and values, set breakpoints in the code and a lot more.